# Restricting magnitude of change in guess in fmin_bfgs

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to estimate a statistical model using MLE in python using the fmin_BFGS function in Scipy.Optimize and a numerically computed Hessian.

It is currently giving me the following warning: `Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss`.

When I print the results of each evaluation, I see that while the starting guess yields a reasonable log-likelihood. However, after a few guesses, the cost function jumps from ~230,000 to 9.5e+179.

Then it gives a runtime warning: `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars` when trying to compute `radical = B * B - 3 * A * C` in the linesearch part of the routine.

I suspect that the algo is trying to estimate the cost function at a point that approaches an overflow. Is there a way to reduce the rate at which the algorithm changes parameter values to keep the function in a well-behaved region? (I would use the constrained BFGS routine but I don't have good priors over what the parameter values should be)

Comment: Could you give [fmin_l_bfgs_b](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) a try, with `bounds=None` ? It's a wrapper for code from 2011 by Nocedal et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem with `fmin_bfgs`.

As far as I could see, the answer is negative. I didn't see a way to limit the stepsize.

My workaround was to first run Nelder-Mead `fmin` for some iterations, and then switch to `fmin_bfgs`. Once I was close enough to the optimum, the curvature of my function was much nicer and `fmin_bfgs` didn't have problems anymore.

In my case the problem was that the gradient of my function was very large at points further away from the optimum.

`fmin_l_bfgs_b` works also without constraints, and several users have reported reliable performance.

aside: If you are able to convert your case to a relatively simple test case, then you could post it to the scipy issue tracker so that a developer or contributor can look into it.

Comment: First Nelder-Mead, then switch, is a good way to defend against a noisy gradient, +1. The scipy Nelder-Mead, by the way, starts off with a **fixed**-size simplex, .05 / .00025 regrdless of the scale of `x` -- [optimize.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py) lines 439 ff.